# Как правильно составить POST запрос при не стандартном типе данных

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Вопрос будет немного нубский, но разобраться немного не удается.

Нужно сделать простой запрос. В запросе передать ID и по нему вернуть некий URL
Сама механика возрата роли не играет. Вопрос стоит в создании запроса (контроллер).

Код контроллера :

```
    [HttpPost("[action]")]
    public async Task<Result<CallRecordDTO>> GetRecord([FromBody] CallId id)
    {
        return await Mediator.Send(new GetRecordRequest() { CallId = id });
    }
```

CallID (я бы поставил просто string, но дальше мне надо менно CallID передать в методо получения URL):

```
public class CallId : ModelBase<string>
{
    public CallId(string value)
        : base(value)
    {
    }
}
```

Далее я делаю в постмане POST запрос по адресу https://localhost:53524/Record/GetRecord
в raw пришу JSON:

```
"CallId" : "avssd"
```

и делаю точку останова внутри контроллера.
в итоге я вхожу в контроллер (да даже без JSON в запросе вхожу) , но в параметр у меня падает null

Как мне передать ID при таком типе данных ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передавай в запросе строку (string), а потом создай объект класса CallId. Примерно так:

```
    [HttpPost("[action]")]
    public async Task<Result<CallRecordDTO>> GetRecord([FromBody] string id)
    {
        var callId = new CallId(id);
        return await Mediator.Send(new GetRecordRequest() { CallId = callId });
    }
```

Единственное, я не уверен, что сравнение будет корректным. Если класс CallId - это модель ORM, то сравнение идёт через его уникальный ключ, обычно `Id` после класса модели. Если это так, то достать этот объект нужно через дополнительный запрос. Тут зависит от ORM, которую используешь.

Comment: Спасибо. Выручили. По теме C# я совсем как хлебушек. На простых вещах тупить начинаю :)
Классы ORM  унас обзывают как Entity. 
Но что там под капотом у запроса URL мне не ведомо. Так как метод запроса я получаю из NuGet пакета.